# How can I Remote Debug Android with a low risk of revealing PII?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

Following the [Chrome Remote Debugging on Android](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) documentation, I am eventually redirected to a web app hosted on AppSpot.com. My organization has strict PII requirements and using an external app like this is a risk for us.

Where can I find the source of the Dev Tools to deploy internally?

I have looked for the dev tools in Blink repo (https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git) and a recent Chromium tarball using `find . -iname devtools.css` and didn't find anything.

I have looked at the network inspector while debugging, and I do not believe the AppSpot app could receive PII currently, but my organization will not take the risk that this may change in the future.

I understand maintaining an internal deploy for all the different Chrome versions will be annoying.

Comment: How exactly did you get from the Chrome Remote Debugging on Android documentation to the AppSpot stuff?  I'm trying to find any documentation I can on how AppSpot works, it appears to be a way to debug and I would like to evaluate if it would be useful to me, but haven't found anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Chrome Canary instead, it has better, more integrated Mobile debugging support.

Plug in your Android device, run `adb devices` from the command line and then in Chrome Canary visit `chrome://inspect`.  Your device should be listed there, and then you can debug the pages on the device **with** the DevTools that come with Chrome and not on the appspot domain.

Comment: I see my device in Chrome Canary, but inspecting doesn't work. When I click on Inspect, a new window opens that looks like the shell of the inspector. There is a gray toolbar on top, without any buttons, and an empty white body below.

Comment: @burkemw3 try again, there was some bugs recently on canary

Comment: Actually debugging android using chrome://inspect requires loading devtools front-end from appspot as before. It is just shown in the same window as the bundled front-end. So this doesn't resolve the problem with access to appspot.com

Comment: @YurySemikhatsky if you use Chrome canary it will not use appspot, you get full access to all your extensions if you use canary.

Comment: The version of Canary I downloaded today worked like a charm.

Comment: can I run Canary on my Android device?  The Canary page seems to suggest that I can download it for Android, but the link re-directs to a Chrome page which suggests I can get "Chrome Beta for Android", but once in the Play Store it shows the regular (non-beta) Chrome that is already installed.

Comment: @Michael even stranger, on the device itself, the Canary page seems to think Android is Linux (which it is, technically, but it's weird that it doesn't recognize that it is actually Android!)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your own location of the DevTools front-end using --remote-debugging-frontend command line flag. The url may be from your local network. You will need to host the front-end files somewhere though. There is some documentation on the flag: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/contributing

Comment: Nice answer, although you won't need this soon.

Comment: Why not, is there an alternative way?